# Convergence in distribution to a chi-squared

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions, convergence-divergence, chi-squared

Let's say I have a sequence of random variables $X_n$ such that $X_n \leadsto N(0,1)$ (convergence in distribution). How can I prove that $X_n^2 \leadsto \chi_{(1)}^2$ without using the continuous mapping theorem?

I'm thinking something like, if $X_n \leadsto N(0,1)$ then $P(X_n \leq x) \rightarrow \Phi(x)$ where $\Phi(x)$ is the CDF of $N(0,1)$, so (suppose $X>0$) $P(X_n^2 \leq x) = P(X_n \leq \sqrt{n}) \rightarrow \Phi(\sqrt{x})$ but now I have the problem to prove that $\Phi(\sqrt{x})$ matches the CDF of the $\chi_{(1)}^2$ (where both CDFs are difficult to write it down in the first place).

Now, if I try with Levy's theorem, $X_n \leadsto N(0,1)$ if and only if $\varphi_{X_n}(t) \rightarrow e^{-t^2/2}$ for all $t$. What I need is $$\varphi_{X_n^2}(t) \rightarrow (1-2it)^{-1/2},$$
but again, I don't know how to conclude this using only the fact that $\varphi_{X_n}(t) \rightarrow e^{-t^2/2}$. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were almost there with the CDF, for $x\geq 0$
$$
P(X_n^2 \leq x) = P(-\sqrt{x}\leq X_n \leq \sqrt{x}) \to P(-\sqrt{x}\leq X \leq \sqrt{x}) =2\Phi(\sqrt{x})-1.
$$
Now it is true that the CDF $2\Phi(\sqrt{x})-1$ is little difficult to see but the PDF is easy, take a derivative and get
$\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}\phi(\sqrt{x})=(2\pi)^{-1/2}x^{-1/2}e^{-x/2}$, when $x>0$, and $0$ otherwise.

If you want to use  Levy's theorem, then
$$
\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\mathbb{E}(e^{itX_n^2}) =\mathbb{E}( e^{itX^2}) = (1-2it)^{-1/2}.
$$
The first equality is due to dominated convergence theorem.

Comment: Thanks, I just have one question. When I derive, I have $(2\Phi(\sqrt{x})-1)' = \frac{2}{\sqrt{x}} \phi(\sqrt{x}).$ Why in your derivative you don't have the $2$ that multiply the $\Phi(\sqrt{x})$??

Comment: @Jeybe Let me try to explain: when you use the chain rule, you differentiate $\sqrt{x}$, you get $\frac{1}{2}x^{-1/2}$ and the $2$ gets canceled, right?

Comment: Right haha, thanks!